# Where to download the marvel for ES 7.10.1

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for the marvel plugin that could work with ES 7.10.1, but I could only find marvel that supports ES 2.x, which is too old. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/index.html

I would ask where to find the zip file of marvel plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Marvel plugin has been deprecated in 2.x and its development discontinued after ES 5.x. All the reporting and monitoring features are now included in [XPack Monitoring as of version 5.x](https://www.elastic.co/blog/x-pack-5-0-0-released):

**Marvel back then:**
[image]

**XPack Monitoring in 5.x:**
[image]

**[XPack Monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch-monitoring) today:**
[image]